# How to split table across pages while keeping some the headline above table..? Windows 7, MS Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a table who is pretty much exactly 2 pages "big". My problem is that I want to have the heading title and some text above the table. The table was initially small, but as it grew past one page, it "jumped" to a blank page and the heading was standing alone on the same page. So now the table is split over page 2 and 3, while the heading and text is standing alone one page 1.

Usually this is no problem, so this is the first time I have encountered this.

Anybody knows how to fix this?!?

Comment: A web search on "repeating headings in word table" (w/o quote marks) will give you several answers. For example, this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repeat-table-header-on-subsequent-pages-2ff677e0-3150-464a-a283-fa52794b4b41   which says to select the header rows you want to repeat then under Table Tools, on the Layout tab, in the Data group, click Repeat Header Rows.

Comment: Are you saying that a single table row has expanded and is now moving to the following page?  The easy way is to add additional rows (and put less text in them).  You can use the border tools to create "invisible" table borders within the table so that they are not visible in a printed document.

Answer (score 0):

You may have the Heading style applied to the table text.  Verify that the text in the table has the "Normal" style applied.

Also, here are a couple things to check under paragraph formatting for the table (display paragraph settings by typing "Paragraph Settings" in Tell Me box, then select "Line and Page Breaks" tab):

Under the pagination section, verify the following (Refer to image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrVnM.jpg)):

1. "Keep lines together" is not checked.
2. "Keep with next" is not checked.
3. "Page break before" is not checked

Under Table Properties, verify that "Allow row to break across pages" is checked.